# Prime generating with bit masking is causing programme to crash

Tags: c++, c++11

In the below code, I have used bitmasking for generating primes butunfortunately it doesn't work properly rather this programme is crashing 
while running.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define maxn 65540
using namespace std;

int _c[(maxn>>6)+1];  //as we will be neede max

int  primes[maxn];


#define IsComp(n)  (_c[n>>6]&(1<<((n>>1)&31)))//to compare bit
#define SetComp(n) _c[n>>6]|=(1<<((n>>1)&31))//to set the bit
void prime_sieve() {
for (int i = 3; i <=maxn; i += 2)
    if (!IsComp(i))
        for (int j = i*i; j <=maxn; j += i+i)
            SetComp(j);//if the number is not primes then it is changed     to  1

primes[0]=2;//first prime is 2;
int   j=1;
for (int i=3; i <= maxn; i += 2)
    if (!IsComp(i))
        primes[j++]=i;//putting the value in primes array;
}
int main()
{

prime_sieve();//calling the function
//Prime();
}
```

Comment: It helps to provide details on how the code crashes? Is it not compiling or giving you a runtime error?

Comment: @AmmarHusain code it compiling but i think while generating those primes the code on my IDE is crashing..by the way thanks for your response.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? And your code formatting is rather horrendous. Also, using global variables is bad practice. And lambdas or function objects should be used rather than macros.

Comment: @c650 thanks for ur concern ,next time i will try to avoid this and again thanks for your advice

Comment: What's `MAX`? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for correcting me..but still have the problem :(

Comment: My eyes hurt! Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648

Comment: if you have found the answer you can post it as answer@leonelshovo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can understand 
When the outer loop (i) runs until 46348 It works well as i*i is under the range 2147483648 but when i becomes 46349 there is integer overflow in j value and it's value becomes -2146737495 and then follows setComp(j) with j as negative.